# MySQL counting results from max()

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that tracks inventory scans in and out of the location. Example data like this:

```
bar_code_id,scan_type,scan_timestamp
038755,in,"2020-03-19 16:58:18"
038755,out,"2020-03-10 12:51:47"
001548,in,"2020-03-06 14:50:41"
012170,in,"2020-03-06 14:50:28"
020166,in,"2020-03-06 14:49:48"
022908,in,"2020-03-06 14:49:07"
012169,out,"2020-03-02 11:48:43"
020182,out,"2020-03-02 11:48:24"
047270,in,"2020-01-29 16:54:18"
020166,out,"2020-01-20 11:43:44"
012170,out,"2020-01-20 11:43:32"
022908,out,"2020-01-20 11:43:23"
001548,out,"2020-01-20 11:43:16"
016852,in,"2020-01-20 09:42:07"
020182,in,"2020-01-20 09:42:02"
012172,out,"2020-01-14 12:56:00"
012172,in,"2020-01-14 11:06:22"
001548,in,"2020-01-14 10:46:47"
010606,in,"2020-01-14 10:46:46"
012169,in,"2020-01-14 10:46:45"
020166,in,"2020-01-14 10:46:45"
010054,in,"2020-01-13 14:59:50"
012167,in,"2020-01-13 14:58:33"
020175,out,"2020-01-09 12:16:16"
023260,in,"2020-01-07 12:01:12"
038755,in,"2020-01-06 09:15:23"
```

I'm trying to create a query that will show the current number inside the building. I am able to find the latest scan of each asset using the following:

```
select bar_code_id, max(scan_timestamp)
from scans
group by bar_code_id
order by bar_code_id
```

Giving the following results:

```
bar_code_id,timestamp
001548,"2020-03-06 14:50:41"
010054,"2020-01-13 14:59:50"
010606,"2020-01-14 10:46:46"
012167,"2020-01-13 14:58:33"
012169,"2020-03-02 11:48:43"
012170,"2020-03-06 14:50:28"
012172,"2020-01-14 12:56:00"
016852,"2020-01-20 09:42:07"
020166,"2020-03-06 14:49:48"
020175,"2020-01-09 12:16:16"
020182,"2020-03-02 11:48:24"
022908,"2020-03-06 14:49:07"
023260,"2020-01-07 12:01:12"
038755,"2020-03-19 16:58:18"
047270,"2020-01-29 16:54:18"
```

But can't work out how to show what the scan type is too. Ideally I would like to be able to count the number of items where the last scan was 'in' and also the total number of items.

Any pointers?

**edit**

I'm trying to only look at the most recent scan for each bar_code and then count the number where the scan_type is 'in'

So the latest scan for each bar_code is:

```
bar_code_id,scan_type,scan_timestamp
001548,in,2020-03-06 14:50:41
010054,in,2020-01-13 14:59:50
010606,in,2020-01-14 10:46:46
012167,in,2020-01-13 14:58:33
012169,out,2020-03-02 11:48:43
012170,in,2020-03-06 14:50:28
012172,out,2020-01-14 12:56:00
016852,in,2020-01-20 09:42:07
020166,in,2020-03-06 14:49:48
020175,out,2020-01-09 12:16:16
020182,out,2020-03-02 11:48:24
022908,in,2020-03-06 14:49:07
023260,in,2020-01-07 12:01:12
038755,in,2020-03-19 16:58:18
047270,in,2020-01-29 16:54:18
```

And then the ones that were type 'in' are:

```
bar_code_id,scan_type,scan_timestamp
001548,in,2020-03-06 14:50:41
010054,in,2020-01-13 14:59:50
010606,in,2020-01-14 10:46:46
012167,in,2020-01-13 14:58:33
012170,in,2020-03-06 14:50:28
016852,in,2020-01-20 09:42:07
020166,in,2020-03-06 14:49:48
022908,in,2020-03-06 14:49:07
023260,in,2020-01-07 12:01:12
038755,in,2020-03-19 16:58:18
047270,in,2020-01-29 16:54:18
```

Giving an answer of 11.

My sql query using max(scan_timestamp) does not include the scan_type so this cannot be counted. If i try to include this then the max function shows more than just the latest scan

```
select bar_code_id, max(scan_timestamp) as timestamp, scan_type
from scans
group by bar_code_id, scan_type

bar_code_id,timestamp,scan_type
038755,"2020-03-19 16:58:18",in
020166,"2020-01-20 11:43:44",out
012170,"2020-01-20 11:43:32",out
022908,"2020-01-20 11:43:23",out
001548,"2020-01-20 11:43:16",out
016852,"2020-01-20 09:42:07",in
020182,"2020-01-20 09:42:02",in
012172,"2020-01-14 12:56:00",out
012172,"2020-01-14 11:06:22",in
001548,"2020-03-06 14:50:41",in
010606,"2020-01-14 10:46:46",in
038755,"2020-03-10 12:51:47",out
012169,"2020-01-14 10:46:45",in
020166,"2020-03-06 14:49:48",in
010054,"2020-01-13 14:59:50",in
012167,"2020-01-13 14:58:33",in
020175,"2020-01-09 12:16:16",out
023260,"2020-01-07 12:01:12",in
012170,"2020-03-06 14:50:28",in
022908,"2020-03-06 14:49:07",in
012169,"2020-03-02 11:48:43",out
020182,"2020-03-02 11:48:24",out
047270,"2020-01-29 16:54:18",in
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is really what you want, but I have this request:

```
SELECT bar_code_id, MAX(scan_timestamp) as timetamps, scan_type, COUNT(scan_type) as number_of_items, (SELECT COUNT(id) from scans) as total
FROM scans
WHERE scan_type = 'in'
GROUP BY bar_code_id
ORDER BY bar_code_id
```

Here is the link where I tested this request: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0da168/19

I'm available if you have a question about my answer.